# I'm trying to export the contents of a process after dynamic linking in order to make a static version of the PE. Can it be done this way?

Tags: linker, x86-64, dynamic-linking, portable-executable

Let's say I have a PE that leverages dynamically linked libs and I want to statically link everything. And I don't have the source code, so using compiler flags isn't an option. I've been trying to figure out how to do this.

It seems like you could most easily accomplish this by letting the dynamic linker do its thing at runtime so that all of the necessary libraries are loaded into the process memory, then basically export that memory and store it statically within the PE, perhaps in the .text section?

Am I completely wrong, or is this a viable approach?

Comment: On Linux/Unix systems, there is/was `undump` which can convert a core dump into a runnable executable.  IIRC, the perl interpreter had an option to do this after parsing a perl script, to bypass some startup overhead(?) and also just to bake the script + interpreter into one executable.  IDK how that interacted with shared libraries.  http://computer-programming-forum.com/53-perl/ab1687f4bb965ac5.htm talks about this not being actually viable recently.  (It couldn't make a position-independent executable for sure; the only ASLR would be before the original core dump.)

Comment: Also related: [Is a core dump executable by itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18274309).  Oh, apparently historically `undump` was also used by TeX distributions, maybe to cache the results of init functions that make tables.

Comment: Although API functions are stable among Windows versions, they are only wrappers of internal kernel functions, for instance `WriteConsoleW` calls `NtDeviceIoControlFile`. Those internal function are different in Windows versions and builds. Even if you managed to implement your approach, such static PortableExecutable file would not be Portable any more. It might crash after Windows update.

Comment: @vitsoft thank you, I was completely overlooking that. So I need to keep specifically the windows kernel libraries dynamically linked. That's the only limitation you're aware of?

Comment: If you want your static PE be redistributable to other computers, they would have to run on identical version of Windows and hardware - at least the video driver, I guess.

Comment: @vitsoft You're saying all / most dynamically linked libraries are uniquely tailored to the particular machine / OS version? I didn't realize that... This idea of static libraries isn't a new idea, at least as far as I can tell: Various endpoint security write-ups mention that some attackers use their own fresh copies of dependencies / use system calls directly to avoid security product hooks patched into those libs / OS APIs (also makes reverse engineering hard)... Which is what I'm trying to PoC here.. So... these attacks must be engineering malware specific to their target environment?